# How to print block_data based on block_type key value in dart

Tags: dart

I have a method where i iterate through list of objects. For each object i want to print the value of 'block_data' based on "block_type" in the order of above to below. Notice that sometimes the `block_type` `title` is above `text` and sometimes its below `text` in the list of objects.

Sometimes i have other `block_types` like `graph-pie-chart` and i have `block_labels` for the chart and the `block_data` for the chart is also in a list based on `block_labels`. And all the `block_type` in the `List` coul be something else and another order. But i still want it in the order of the List of objects i get like the example below. I wonder how i can achieve this with dart?

```
class Book {
  getBookInfo() {
    final List listOfItems = [
      {"block_type": "title", "block_data": "Books"},
      {"block_type": "text", "block_data": "This is the textblock of books"},
      {"block_type": "text", "block_data": "This is the textblock of publishers"},
      {"block_type": "title", "block_data": "Publishers"},
      {"block_type": "graph-pie-chart", "block_labels": ["Total sold","Sold copies","Reviews"], "block_data": ["3000", "100", "10"]},
      {"block_type": "button", "link": "<link to a bookshop>"},
    ];
    List selectedItem = listOfItems;
    selectedItem.forEach((index) {

      }
      ;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While strictly speaking, you are not incorrect to call each element of the list an object, they are more precisely of type [`Map<String,String>`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#maps)

You can use [`.where()`](https://dart.dev/codelabs/iterables?linkId=81037340#example-using-where) to filter out maps that do not have a key of block_type and value of the block type that you need, then do your `.forEach()` to print the value you want.

You also might consider defining a class type to use instead of a Map in your listOfItems